# how to use "in" and "on" different things

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on

There is a really big confusion in me when it comes to using "in" and "on". If I am describing a position of an object I know how the two words differ, but when it comes to other things it really confuses.

e.g

> in photo or on photo
>   in website or on website
>   in phone or on phone
>   in the movie or on the movie
>   in his account or on his account

How do we figure out which is the word to use in such occasions? What are the rules to get them right?

Comment: *In* always has an element of meaning *inside*. If something does not feature *in* something, it's probably *on*. *In* a photo, movie or account; *on* the phone. Usually it's also *on* a website (like it's *on* a wall). And generally articles are required.

Comment: Generally, _in_ refers to three-dimensional spaces or containers (_in the jar, in a box, in the yard_), while _on_ refers to two-dimensional surfaces (_on the ground, on a table, on the lawn_). Note that  _yard_ is three-dimensional, while _lawn_ is two-dimensional. This rule does not apply to prepositions that are governed by predicates (_rule on, interested in_), prepositions that are part of phrasal verbs (_take it on, take him in_), or prepositions that are part of idioms (_in time, on time, in a hurry, on a mission_).

Comment: We have a [whole collection](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-on) of questions dedicated to choosing between *in* and *on*. I suggest you take a look. On a general note, prepositions are always the trickiest part when learning a language (that has them), and your best bet is not to learn any rules, because there will *always* be exceptions, but just to learn everything by heart. After all, that's exactly what native speakers do. If you want to really master the language, follow their example.